# how to cause react to re-render checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, rerender

So, I am getting a list of data from the backend

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const getDataSet = async () => {
const { data } = await inapp.get('/v1/vcr/getData');
setData(data.payload);

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);
```

I am rendering a list of checkboxes using the array map function
Then, I have a button

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
  const handleToggle = (value) => {
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }
    setChecked(newChecked);
  };
  const renderDataCheckboxes = () => {
    return (
      <div className={classes.inlineChecks}>
        {data.map((row) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              key={row.id}
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  onClick={() => handleToggle(row.name)}
                  checked={checked.indexOf(row.name) !== -1}
                  checkedIcon={<Check className={classes.checkedIcon} />}
                  icon={<Check className={classes.uncheckedIcon} />}
                  classes={{
                    checked: classes.checked,
                    root: classes.checkRoot,
                  }}
                />
              }
              classes={{ label: classes.label }}
              label={row.name}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

I also have a button that will remove the checked items from the backend.  Question is, how do I cause the checkboxes to re-render to remove the deleted items?

Comment: If i understand correct you want if some one checked that checkbox. You want to remove from checkbox list?

Comment: is the useState for data and useState for checked two different components? Because your handleToggle function updates your `checked` array but you're actually rendering `data` state. If you want your component to re-render then in your handleToggle function, update the data slice of state.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Hyetigran in the function the the button invoke to delete data from the backend, I am refreshing the data from there.

Comment: @Bill Then you can filter the data. If checkbox is true dont show on ui

Comment: it turns out it has something to do with the async await function calls to the backend.  For some reason, the call is not updating my state variable.  I have posted a separate question on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 4 methods to re-render components in react, not necessarily CheckBox

https://linguinecode.com/post/4-methods-to-re-render-react-component

Although it works, `forceRender()` is not recommendded anywhere

Answer (score 0):

this was due to the way i handled the deletion.  I was using foreach and apparently it fires await calls without waiting.  I switched to for..of loop and it works.  Please see my other post for more details.

[async await not behaving as expected in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63828489/async-await-not-behaving-as-expected-in-reactjs)