# async await not behaving as expected in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const getData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/getData');
    setData(data.payload);
  };
```

and a button to call handleDelete from the backend

```
  const handleDelete = async () => {
    checked.forEach(async (element) => {
      await axios.delete('/deleteData', {
        data: { data: element },
      });
    });
    await getData();
    console.log(data);
  };
```

The data is deleted from the backend, I have components that depends on data in React and for some reason, data is not being updated.  The component is not updating with the new values.

Does anyone know what I might doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It _might_ have something to do with how you are using the `.forEach()`.  The data is probably deleted from the backend correctly, but not before you make the request to actually go and get the data.  `getData` won't wait for the `forEach` to finish before firing.  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @zero298 Thank you so much!  That was it!  I didn't know foreach doesn't wait.  Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

Try using async iterators for your request and see if it works.

You could read about async iterators in details [here](https://javascript.info/async-iterators-generators)

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
    for await (const element of checked) {
        await axios.delete('/deleteData', {
        data: { data: element },
      });
    }
    await getData();
    console.log(data);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to zero298 for answering this question.  It was due to the forEach loop firing the await call and not waiting.  I changed to for..of and it's now working!